# No Date and Time on 14.10

Tags: 14.10, system-settings, time, date

When starting up my machine (Ubuntu 14.10) just now I have noticed that the bit in the top bar which tells me the date and time is gone, and I am unable for some strange reason to change the `Date & Time > Clock` settings:

[image: Date & Time Clock settings greyed out]

Why are the settings greyed out and why is the Date and Time not showing in the top bar? And how can I fix this? Or is this some sort of bug which I should report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date/time indicator applet has either been accidentally removed or is not configured.

Start by trying to re-install it. (If you already have it, then you can ignore the message saying the latest version is already installed).

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

Now configure it.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

And finally get Unity to reload it.

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  Next time, use 4 spaces in front of the commands you're typing so KasiyA doesn't have to edit your answer to make it excellent!  **:P  ;-)**  So please review [his edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/587446/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future.

Comment: @Fabby Thank you for the feedback. Duly noted, but I have a question - please see Meta.